# keyboard does not show glob icon for change language

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to use arabic language in my app.  i add the arabic keyboard from setting, but when keyboard appear from  secure NSTextfield, keyboard does not show the language change icon on keyboard. it working fine in normal NSTextField. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add few keyboard types in your settings

Go to Device Setting-->General-->International-->Keyboards-->Add new Keyboards.

Comment: You can do the same for simulator also(If you are debugging in iPhone Simulator)